# stsadm command script for SharePoint 2007 run via Task scheduler job

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007, stsadm

I want to write one script in STSADM which checks SharePoint 2007 site collection lock status and if any site status is locked/Read-Only/Adding Content Prevented/No Access then the script will Unlock that site.

Following command to check site status: `stsadm -o getsitelock -URL Siteurl`

Following command for unlock site: `stsadm -o setsitelock SiteURL -lock none`

I have a list of the site collection in the text file.

*Now I need help how to write these in a script and schedule them via Task Scheduler job. In addition, I want to add email sending functionality in the same script if any site gets locked.*

Answer (score 0):

here is a script, schedule it under Farm Administrator with [PSShellAdmin](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/add-spshelladmin?view=sharepoint-ps) privilegies. You can do enum all sites or just at start load your file with sites in `$Sites`.

```
asnp *sharepoint* 
$Sites = Get-SPSite -Limit All

foreach($Site in $Sites)
{
    $Lock = STSADM.exe -o getsitelock -Url $Site.Url
    $Lock[1]
    if($Lock[1] -eq '<SiteLock Lock="none" />')
    {
        Write-Host "$($Site.Url) OK" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else
    {
        STSADM.exe -o setsitelock -Url $Site.Url -lock none
        Write-Host "$($Site.Url) was unlocked" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
}
```

*Hope it helps!*